# log4j-api 2.20.0 causing : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil

Tags: java, log4j, java-17

My java:17.0.5 Application is based on struts2-core:6.3.0.2 and I am using the log4j-api:2.17.2 as the dependency and the application is running fine.
When log4j-api uplifted to 2.20.0 (supported by struts), I am getting below exception. That I am not able to comprehend.

```
SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter [Struts2Filter]
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil
                at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<clinit>(StatusLogger.java:77)
                at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:61)
                at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.<clinit>(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:49)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:143)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:242)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:97)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4311)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4940)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1014)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1866)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:816)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:468)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1584)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:312)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:345)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:794)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:248)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:925)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:735)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
        


Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key can't be empty [in thread "main"]
                at java.base/java.lang.System.checkKey(System.java:1049)
                at java.base/java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:912)
                at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.SystemPropertiesPropertySource.getProperty(SystemPropertiesPropertySource.java:96)
                at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.SystemPropertiesPropertySource.containsProperty(SystemPropertiesPropertySource.java:104)
                at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil$Environment.lambda$null$2(PropertiesUtil.java:498)
                at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
                at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil$Environment.lambda$reload$3(PropertiesUtil.java:497)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
                at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1707)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
                at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil$Environment.reload(PropertiesUtil.java:494)
                at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil$Environment.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:469)
                at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil$Environment.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:444)
                at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:88)
                at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:80)
                at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.<clinit>(PropertiesUtil.java:56)
                at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Constants.<clinit>(Constants.java:30)
                at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.createClassForProperty(AbstractLogger.java:203)
                at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.<clinit>(AbstractLogger.java:92)
                ... 51 more
```

I try adding log4j-core:2.20.0 to class path, That didn't change a thing.

Comment: Does this occur with the current version (`2.23.1`)? If so, [submit a bug report](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues).

Comment: Yes, with version 2.23.1 also I'm still getting same error. I have reported a bug : https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/2414

Comment: You are using a deprecated API. Post your [MCVE] if you want to reproduce the issue